# ImportError: cannot import name _hierarchy or DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, jupyter

I've been working on a project in a Jupyter notebook, and wanted to use dedupe. Through anaconda, only dedupe-hcluster is available on a windows machine, so I installed that and attempted to import hcluster within the notebook, which gave this error:

"ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application."

From what I've read up on, this means that either Python is 32 bit whilst hcluster is 64 bit, or vice versa. It's not clear to me however how to fix this.

I then tried to convert the notebook into a Pycharm script so that I may use another version of dedupe, either dedupe, dedupe-hcluster or pandas-dedupe. I had issues installing pandas-dedupe, so went with the two former. Importing dedupe gives this error:

"ImportError: No module named _lowlevel"

and importing hcluster gives this error:

"ImportError: cannot import name _hierarchy"

I've done what feels like endless reading on all 3 of these issues and am no closer to solving any of them.
Any suggestions on how to fix any of the above will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to install 64 bit version of Python; you can check which version you are using with the following:

```
import struct
print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))
```

This will output 32 or 64

Then make sure dedupe is installed correctly.  The Dedupe library has a good sized wheel, but it installs easily. (Easily on Python3, not sure about Python2)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Anaconda and a Jupyter notebook, make sure your Anaconda environment is active in your notebook.